# What size drain is required for a washing machine?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

What is the plumbing Code for Washing Machine Drain?

I want to install an extra washer and dryer in my detached two car garage.

This is a picture from a house under construction.

I believe the Drain is 2 inches. Then it appears to be upsized to a 3 inch PVC in the crawlspace.

[image: Washing Machine Plumbing]

Answer (score 4):

You're correct, the requirement for washing machine drain is 2".

To determine if you have enough drain capacity for an additional machine, you need to consult the Uniform Plumbing Code's **Drainage Fixture Unit** values and ensure the total fixtures don't exceed the capacity of the drain for your laundry room (or plan an upgrade.)

These tables should help get you started:

- Fixture values https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drainage-fixture-unit-values-d_1077.html
- Drain capacity per pipe size in stacks & branches https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drainage-fixture-units-piping-load-d_1078.html